# Android 4.2 how drop caches in java?

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i've created an little app which drop cache with UNIX command

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

When a radio button is clicked. Everything goes well and when i type on terminal emulator the 
"free" command the free memory is more. Is there the same function but in java?

Comment: You can try opening the file /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches as a FileOutputStream and write '3' to it. If you don't need root permissions to do so this should work.

Comment: The app goes well, but needs root. There are some apps in the play store like ram booster that shows your free ram memory before and after click the button to drop cache. This ap, for example, doesn't needs root so i think the command is different from mine and i think the developer use the android api (java) but i can't find something like this!

Comment: You can also execute command lines via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

Comment: yeah, but in java language? i mean something like this : echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches but in java. Without root permission. Something like the the "clear cache" in Task settings in the samsung.